# Django Foreign Key Create Form Get Instance

Tags: django, django-forms

When I am creating a new object with a foreign key field, is there a way in the template to get the foreign key object fields in the template on the create form? Whenever I create a new note I would like to have: "Add new note to {{ applicant.full_name }}"

```
class Applicant(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=128,blank=False, verbose_name="First Name")
    middle_name = models.CharField(max_length=128,blank=True, verbose_name="Middle Name")
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=128,blank=False, verbose_name="Last Name")

    @property
    def full_name(self):
        "Returns the applicant's full name."
        return '%s %s %s' % (self.first_name, self.middle_name, self.last_name)

class Note(models.Model):
    applicant = models.ForeignKey(Applicant, related_name='notes', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
)
```

(Updated) Here is the view:

```
class NoteCreate(CreateView):
    model = Note
    form_class = forms.NoteForm
    template_name = 'careers/add_note.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        applicant_pk = self.kwargs['pk']
        applicant = Applicant.objects.get(pk=applicant_pk)
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        self.object.applicant = applicant
        self.object.save()
        return super(NoteCreate, self).form_valid(form)
```

Comment: And does `{{ note.applicant.full_name }}` not work for you?

Comment: Sorry, I should've mentioned that. No, I tried that as well. The URL is {% url 'app_name:add_note' applicant.pk %}

Comment: Can you show full code you tried?

Comment: I added the view to the code.

Comment: No, I mean template.